# How calculate work from an electric field on a $+q$ particle without the curve?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, work, gauss-law

Well,i've a workout for home,and it is asking me to calculate the work from the electric field with equation: $\hat E=6xy \hat x+(3x^2-y^2)\hat y$
I tried to solve the line integral but it doesn't give us a line in order to solve it.So how i'll calculate it?

Comment: Welcome. $$\boldsymbol{\nabla \times}\mathbf{E} \boldsymbol{=} \textbf{???}$$ although you don't show any effort and your question must be closed.

Comment: Think about electric potential $\Phi$ for your field $\vec{E}$

Comment: You need to specify a path along which to do that integral, or use the potential, first prove that it is conservative?  Show some effort in what you've tried.  Your statement "I tried to solve the line integral but it doesn't give us a line in order to solve it" does not make sense to me as it shouldn't "give a line".

Comment: @ggcg I proved that it is conservative.I tried to solve integral by using transforms with variable t but I need a curve-line in order to do this. how can I handle this?

Comment: If it is conservative then you are in luck!  as the result is path independent.  So pick any path from your starting point (say infinity) to an arbitrary point.  try finding a potential function that gives E as its -gradient, then you have work done for any pair of points.

Comment: @ggcg It is asking me to calculate work from (0.0.0) to (Xo.0.0). So? I'm a bit lost.

Comment: dx is your path differential.  y = 0 along that path, it is a straight line.  I think you have enough data to start writing it down.  I also think you should provide your attempt if you expect further help.

Comment: You've got two options. $W=q\int_C \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{x}$, along the curve. Or you can use $W=-q\cdot\Delta V$, where $V$ is the potential. Since they don't give you the curve... what way would you choose?

Comment: @ggcg so my parammetrical equation of path is $\hat r=t \hat i$?

Comment: @FGSUZ i tryed to go with the potential V,but i am a little confused.

Comment: You say you are confused, but you don't tell us why, at what point? What's the question? Or are you awaiting for us to do your homework? If you've got a question, fell free to ask. Consider writing a separte question if it is too unrelated.

Answer (score 1):

In general, a path is needed. However, whenever you integrate a conservative vector field, which is your case, the integral is independent of the path. That means two things: first, you can choose any path you want; second, you do not need to choose a path at all, because the integral you seek depends on the value of the scalar field (electrostatic potential) that generates the vector field (electrostatic field) at the starting and ending points alone. So, in order to solve this problem you need to answer/show: is your vector field conservative? If so, what scalar field produces it? How to use this scalar field to calculate the path integral? (hint: fundamental theorem of Calculus)